# Eclipse Mars + Wildfly 9 + deployment not working

Tags: spring, maven, deployment, wildfly, eclipse-mars

I have a Java Spring application, configured in Eclipse Mars and I am running Wildfly 9 from within Eclipse. I am using the wildfly-maven-plugin to deploy to server.

These are the steps I follow:

1. Start the server from Eclipse and do `maven build` which also deploys the application to server. I can see whole lot of logs on server of "successful deployment"and I can access my application in browser. It creates a folder under "/standalone/data/content" but no war or exploded WAR under "standalone/deployments"
2. If I change some code and save it in Eclipse, (I have checked Automatically publish check box and build on save), the server logs says:

> Replaced deployment "myApp.war" with deployment "myApp.war"
>
> Content removed from location "standalone\data\content..."

And I see the prev folder created during step 1 is removed and myApp.war is added to deployment folder. But now I can not access my application in browser.

```
auto-deploy-exploded="true"
```

That is in the  section of `standalone.xml`.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.